# How to report a bug that occured during a release upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, bug-reporting

Launchpad redirects me to a FAQ page and `ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader` complains the package does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to report it against the `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` package:

```
ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

Although it will appear to be linked to the [`ubuntu-release-upgrader` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader).